# Insert on controller action into another controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-file-upload

I am trying to add a controller action into another controller actions because I have an index page that lists a bunch of files. On that same page, I have a file upload sheet and I would like to call the document#new controller#method with the Home#index controller method.  I tried include, but it gave me a uninitialized constant HomeController::DocumentController error.  Any help appreciated.

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController


  def index

      if user_signed_in?
          #show folders shared by others
          @being_shared_folders = [] #current_user.shared_folders_by_others


         #show only root folders (which have no parent folders)
         @folders = current_user.folders.roots 

         #show only root files which has no "folder_id"
         @documents = current_user.documents.where("folder_id is NULL").order("name desc") 

         include DocumentController::new


        else
          redirect_to sign_up_index_path   
      end
   end

end



class DocumentsController < ApplicationController

  def new
      @document = current_user.documents.build    
      if params[:folder_id] #if we want to upload a file inside another folder
       @current_folder = current_user.folders.find(params[:folder_id])
       @document.folder_id = @current_folder.id
      end    
   end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store actions in a common module, and include that module into whatever controller needs it:

```
# lib/common_actions.rb
module CommonActions
  def index
    # whatever
  end
end

# app.controllers/home_controller.rb
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  include CommonActions
end

# app.controllers/documents_controller.rb
class DocumentsController < ApplicationController
  include CommonActions
end
```

Comment: is it worth creating a whole module for one action used only in two places, or is it just better to repeat the code?

Comment: My own preference is to avoid repetition, and I think that creating a module to do that is a small, worthwhile price.